# Error con el carrito de compras

Tags: php, session

Estoy trabajando con un carrito de compras y trato de agregar un botón que elimine un producto a la vez. Pero al tratar de eliminar un producto, termino vaciando la `session` y me vacía el carrito completo.

Lo que quiero hacer es agregar un boton que elimine solo un producto.

carrito.php

```
<?php session_start(); 
//aqui empieza el carrito

if(isset($_SESSION['carrito'])){
    $carrito_mio=$_SESSION['carrito'];
    if(isset($_POST['titulo'])){
        $titulo=$_POST['titulo'];
        $precio=$_POST['precio'];
        $preciocompra=$_POST['preciocompra'];
        $cantidad=$_POST['cantidad'];
        $id=$_POST['id'];
        $num=0;
        $carrito_mio[]=array("titulo"=>$titulo,"precio"=>$precio, "preciocompra"=>$preciocompra,"cantidad"=>$cantidad,"id"=>$id);
    }
}else{
    $titulo=$_POST['titulo'];
    $precio=$_POST['precio'];
    $preciocompra=$_POST['preciocompra'];
    $cantidad=$_POST['cantidad'];
    $id=$_POST['id'];
    $carrito_mio[]=array("titulo"=>$titulo,"precio"=>$precio, "preciocompra"=>$preciocompra,"cantidad"=>$cantidad,"id"=>$id);   
}


$_SESSION['carrito']=$carrito_mio;

//aqui termina el carrito

header("Location: ".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']."");
?>
```

productos.php

```
<?php

if(isset($_SESSION['carrito'])){
    $total=0;
    $productosid= array();
    $productoscantidad=array();

    for($i=0;$i<=count($carrito_mio)-1;$i ++){
        if($carrito_mio[$i]!=NULL){
?>
<li class="mb-2">
<div class="row">

<div class="col-8">
<?php
echo $carrito_mio[$i]['cantidad'] ?> x <?php echo $carrito_mio[$i]['titulo']; 
array_push($productosid, $carrito_mio[$i]['id']);
array_push($productoscantidad, $carrito_mio[$i]['cantidad']);
?>
</div>

<div class="col-4">
<div class="float-end">
$<?php echo $carrito_mio[$i]['precio'] * $carrito_mio[$i]['cantidad']; ?>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</li>
<?php
$total=$total + ($carrito_mio[$i]['precio'] * $carrito_mio[$i]['cantidad']);
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Captura

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradezco la ayuda de antemano

Comment: No logro descifrar dónde exactamente intentas borrar el producto del carrito.

Comment: Concuerdo, donde esta el boton de vaciar carrito y su funcion ?